# PHP debugging a preg-replace callback function

Tags: php, eclipse, callback, preg-replace, xdebug

I'm using Exlipse with Xdebug to debug my php codes, which works well. But there is one type of codes I can't debug: **callback functions**

I'm using preg_replace:

```
$pc = preg_replace('#\[div(=(.*))?\](.*?)\[/div\]#iuUe', "\bbcode_div('\$2', '\$3')", $_POST["data"]);
```

which calls the function all right, but the eclipse wont get inside the function while debugging, even with a break point.

How can I make the debugger to get inside that function?

**EDIT:**  I need to use preg_replace.

Comment: Using `eval` for parsing BBCode is probably very risky, to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
preg_replace_callback('/ /', 'replace', 'this is not a complicated matter');

function replace($t)
{
   var_dump($t);    // <-- set breakpoint here
}
```

This brakes five times before calling `var_dump()`.

---

**EDIT:** Some hackery is required when `preg_replace()` is used with the `e` modifier. In this case, setting a breakpoint is not sufficient. You'd have to explicitly tell XDebug to break:

```
function replace($t)
{
   // Production systems might (should) not have this function
   if (function_exists('xdebug_break'))
   {
      xdebug_break();
   }

   // Rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: can this be used with preg_replace as well? because in another code i am forced to use that.

Comment: Actually, Xdebug does support setting breakpoints in eval'ed statements. I think it's just that Eclipse hasn't implemented support for dbgp://xx files. This type of files are "pseudo files" that Xdebug uses to emulate eval'ed code as files.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Derick. Let's hope the support for these pseudo files will be implemented at some point. It's a pain to debug with Eclipse when you hit a recognized breakpoint and the trace goes *through* an `eval()`. It'll constantly complain (i.e. every *step*) that it doesn't know the source...

Comment: If replace() is not called, all you know is that the pattern didn't match. How to debug a pattern mismatch is a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

First, I wanted to mention to use `preg_replace_callback`. I know that you mention that you must use `preg_replace` (without giving any reasons), but I will tell you first, what you should do and explain why `preg_replace` is bad choice.

Your code looks like this:

```
$pc = preg_replace('#\[div(=(.*))?\](.*?)\[/div\]#iuUe', "\bbcode_div('\$2', '\$3')", $_POST["data"]);
```

It could be rewritten into following:

```
<?php
$regex = '{\[div(?:=(.*?))?\](.*??)\[/div\]}iu';
$pc = preg_replace_callback($regex, function ($matches) {
    return bbcode_div($matches[1], $matches[2]);
});
```

Or following if you still use PHP 5.2 or older (update, seriously).

```
<?php
$regex = '{\[div(?:=(.*?))?\](.*??)\[/div\]}iu';
$pc = preg_replace_callback($regex, create_function('$matches', '
    return bbcode_div($matches[1], $matches[2]);
'));
```

Now, I'm going to explain why `/e` is bad choice. It gives false feeling of security. When using double-quotes in replacement, your security is practically broken.

```
<?php
$_POST['code'] = 'echo "broken";';
$_POST['data'] = '[div]{${eval($_POST[code])}}[/div]';
$pc = preg_replace('#\[div(=(.*))?\](.*?)\[/div\]#iuUe', 'bbcode_div("$2", "$3")', $_POST["data"]);
```

When using `'` characters, `addslashes()` escapes when it shouldn't (`/e` uses `addslashes` internally!). So if user would type `"` character, it would be changed into `\"` when doing call (in single-quotes, `\` can only escape `\` and `'` or else it's inserted literally). It's probably not something you want. `/e` modifier is broken. Well, at least that in PHP. The Perl one is fine...

Certain projects were affected by it, for example roundcube, which used `/e` modifier. It caused [changes in codebase](http://trac.roundcube.net/changeset/2148). Why bother with hacker attacks if you can protect against them simply by not using `/e` modifier.

Also, read https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_preg_replace_eval_modifier (it's already accepted, and next PHP major version (PHP 5.5 or PHP 6.0) will deprecate this modifier).

Comment: I'm doing a PHPBB modification, and phpbb uses preg_replace with /e, thats why i need to use it as well.

Comment: @NaGel182: But this doesn't mean you have to do this same. This is called implementation detail.